# How go back to view when select button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have create a button which looks like this image.
[image]

on every button i have set different views. And use this code for change view...
below code is for about view

```
 - (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl {
NSLog(@"segmentedControl %i did select index %i (via UIControl method)", segmentedControl.tag, segmentedControl.selectedIndex);

switch (segmentedControl.selectedIndex)
{
    case 0: 
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        break;
    }
    case 1:{

        tr=[[[Table_review alloc]initWithNibName:@"Table_review" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        tr.dv=self;
        tr.business_obj=business;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pv_Object animated:NO];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

    }
        break;
        case 2:
    {

        pv_Object=[[[Photo_View alloc]initWithNibName:@"Photo_View" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        pv_Object.dv=self;
        pv_Object.business_obj=business;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pv_Object animated:NO];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    }
            break;


}   
 }
```

below code is for review view

```
 - (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl {
NSLog(@"segmentedControl %i did select index %i (via UIControl method)", segmentedControl.tag, segmentedControl.selectedIndex);


        switch (segmentedControl.selectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: 
        {

            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];

            break;
        }
        case 1:     
            [super viewDidLoad];
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            pv_Object=[[[Photo_View alloc]initWithNibName:@"Photo_View" bundle:nil]autorelease];
            pv_Object.tr_Object=self;
            pv_Object.business_obj=business_obj;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:pv_Object animated:NO];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
        }
            break;



    }

}
```

below code is for photo view

```
- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl {
NSLog(@"segmentedControl %i did select index %i (via UIControl method)", segmentedControl.tag, segmentedControl.selectedIndex);

switch (segmentedControl.selectedIndex)
{
    case 0: 
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        break;
    }
    case 1:{

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
        break;
    case 2:
    {

        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
        break;


}

}
```

Now problem is that when go to fist about to review and review to photo and about from photo. then it kill the program.
So what i change in third code so that it will work fine?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why don't you use the tab component from Apple ?

Answer (score 0):

In first part of code replace :

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pv_Object animated:NO];
```

with this

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tr animated:NO];
```

Comment: When i come back on auto from photo then it crash. From ur help nothing happened. Sp tell what chance in third part?

Comment: And remove lines `[super viewDidLoad];` everywhere

Comment: if remove this line then how load self view when click on itself?